# Tkinker, multithreading problem, terminate and run script

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm completely new to coding and have little to no experience. I have coded a super-simple macro script that when I press a key it till writing a word and press enter and it works well. I wanna understand coding better so I decided to try to build a GUI using Tkinter and used multithreading to keep it from crashing. I'm having a problem creating working buttons for terminating the threads and starting the script, I have managed to get the start button working but then the terminate will not, and now I got the terminate button to work but now the script to work. It gives an argument error that start() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given. I would appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code (it's probably shit) and give me some insight into what I'm doing wrong and what I can improve thank you!

```
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.geometry("450x350")
top.title("Kuk")

def start():
 start= true

 #my script

def exit():
 exit_flag = False
 t = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(lambda: exit_flag,))
 t.start()
 time.sleep(0.1)
 print('Done sleeping! Time to stop the threads.')
 exit_flag = True
 t.join()
 print('THREAD TERMINATED!')
 global top
 top.destroy()
 tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Program closed")

button1= B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="exit", command = exit)
button1.place(x=200, y=25)
button2= B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="start", command = threading.Thread(target=start).start())
button2.place(x=125, y=25)

B.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

I see that the start=true part isn't really doing anything cuz true isn't with a capital T but without it, it will not work

Comment: `args=(lambda: exit_flag,)` probably isn't doing what you think it is. You're creating an anonymous function that does nothing. I don't know if that's the main problem, but it seems to be _a_ problem.

Comment: `command = threading.Thread(target=start).start()` will execute `start()` function *immediately in the main thread*.  You need to use `lambda`: `command = lambda: threading.Thread(target=start).start()`.

Comment: The `def start()` function is defined with no argument. Now when you are calling that function form the lin e`threading.Thread(target=start, args=(lambda: exit_flag,))` in your `exit` function it is passing argument to it.

Hence, the error "start() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given"

Now, from my experience python multithreading and TKinter does not gel well. You need to be careful while using multithreading with Tkinter.